# Is it possible to create nested setOnCheckedChangeListener in android?

Tags: android, uiswitch

```
GroupView.mSwitchForReminder.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        for (int i = 0; i < GroupView.GetCount(); i++) {
            ItemView itemView = (ItemView) GroupView.GetItemView(i);
            if (isChecked) {
                itemView.SetReminderStatus(true);
            } else {
                itemView.SetReminderStatus(false);
            }
            itemView.mSwitchForReminder1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {

                    } else {
                        itemView.SetReminderStatus(false);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }
});
```

I am calling setOnCheckedChangeListener inside setOnCheckedChangeListener. Will it work? When I clicked itemview switch nothing is happening.

Comment: I fixed some issue in your code with `}` and `)`, I suggest you to check it in your side if it's well done

Comment: yes its well done